# Unordered layers in tikz-3dplot (3d effect)

Tags: tikz-pgf, 3d, tikz-3dplot

### Short formulation of the question

Is there a way to order layers in tikz-3dplot according to their distance to the observer's position? The picture should look realistic in order to give some intuition to the reader. But I prefer a solution without rearranging all items of the graphic.

### Example

The following working example does not show the correct 3D view, i.e. the balls are wrong ordered in the second picture:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
 \node[fill=red,circle] (c1) at (0,0,0) {};
 \node[fill=gray,circle] (c2) at (1,0,0) {};
 \node[fill=blue,circle] (c3) at (1,0,1) {};
 \node[fill=green,circle] (c4) at (0,0,1) {};
 \node[fill=black,circle] (c5) at (0,1,0) {};
 \node[fill=orange,circle] (c6) at (1,1,0) {};
 \node[fill=yellow,circle] (c7) at (1,1,1) {};
 \node[fill=magenta,circle] (c8) at (0,1,1) {};
 \draw[line width=2pt] (c1) -- (c2) -- (c3) -- (c4) -- (c1);
 \draw[line width=2pt] (c5) -- (c6) -- (c7) -- (c8) -- (c5);
 \draw[line width=2pt] (c1) -- (c5);
 \draw[line width=2pt] (c2) -- (c6);
 \draw[line width=2pt] (c3) -- (c7);
 \draw[line width=2pt] (c4) -- (c8);
\end{tikzpicture}

\tdplotsetmaincoords{45}{0}
\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords]
 \node[fill=red,circle] (c1) at (0,0,0) {};
 \node[fill=gray,circle] (c2) at (1,0,0) {};
 \node[fill=blue,circle] (c3) at (1,0,1) {};
 \node[fill=green,circle] (c4) at (0,0,1) {};
 \node[fill=black,circle] (c5) at (0,1,0) {};
 \node[fill=orange,circle] (c6) at (1,1,0) {};
 \node[fill=yellow,circle] (c7) at (1,1,1) {};
 \node[fill=magenta,circle] (c8) at (0,1,1)
 \draw[line width=2pt] (c1) -- (c2) -- (c3) -- (c4) -- (c1);
 \draw[line width=2pt] (c5) -- (c6) -- (c7) -- (c8) -- (c5);
 \draw[line width=2pt] (c1) -- (c5);
 \draw[line width=2pt] (c2) -- (c6);
 \draw[line width=2pt] (c3) -- (c7);
 \draw[line width=2pt] (c4) -- (c8);
\end{tikzpicture}

\tdplotsetmaincoords{54.7}{45}
\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords]
 \node[fill=red,circle] (c1) at (0,0,0) {};
 \node[fill=gray,circle] (c2) at (1,0,0) {};
 \node[fill=blue,circle] (c3) at (1,0,1) {};
 \node[fill=green,circle] (c4) at (0,0,1) {};
 \node[fill=black,circle] (c5) at (0,1,0) {};
 \node[fill=orange,circle] (c6) at (1,1,0) {};
 \node[fill=yellow,circle] (c7) at (1,1,1) {};
 \node[fill=magenta,circle] (c8) at (0,1,1) {};
 \draw[line width=2pt] (c1) -- (c2) -- (c3) -- (c4) -- (c1);
 \draw[line width=2pt] (c5) -- (c6) -- (c7) -- (c8) -- (c5);
 \draw[line width=2pt] (c1) -- (c5);
 \draw[line width=2pt] (c2) -- (c6);
 \draw[line width=2pt] (c3) -- (c7);
 \draw[line width=2pt] (c4) -- (c8);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

### Further outlook

Maybe it is crucial to note that I want to use different view angles (feature of `[tikz-3dplot][1]`) without ordering the entire crystal with respect to the appearing layers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

a solution with PSTricks. Run it with `xelatex` (takes some time for the animation) or use `latex->dvips->ps2pdf`

```
\documentclass[pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-solides3d}

\begin{document}

\psset{unit=2}
\multido{\iA=0+10}{38}{%
\begin{pspicture}[solidmemory](-2,-2)(2,2)
\psset{viewpoint=100 \iA\space 20 rtp2xyz,Decran=100}
\psSolid[object=cube,a=1,action=draw,name=my_cube]
\psset{object=point,definition=solidgetsommet,R=10}
\psSolid[args=my_cube 0,linecolor=red]
\psSolid[args=my_cube 1,linecolor=gray]
\psSolid[args=my_cube 2,linecolor=blue]
\psSolid[args=my_cube 3,linecolor=green]
\psSolid[args=my_cube 4,linecolor=black]
\psSolid[args=my_cube 5,linecolor=orange]
\psSolid[args=my_cube 6,linecolor=yellow]
\psSolid[args=my_cube 7,linecolor=magenta]
\end{pspicture}
\newpage}
\multido{\iA=0+10}{36}{%
\begin{pspicture}[solidmemory](-2,-2)(2,2)
\psset{viewpoint=100 20 \iA\space rtp2xyz,Decran=100}
\psSolid[object=cube,a=1,action=draw,name=my_cube]
\psset{object=point,definition=solidgetsommet,R=10}
\psSolid[args=my_cube 0,linecolor=red]
\psSolid[args=my_cube 1,linecolor=gray]
\psSolid[args=my_cube 2,linecolor=blue]
\psSolid[args=my_cube 3,linecolor=green]
\psSolid[args=my_cube 4,linecolor=black]
\psSolid[args=my_cube 5,linecolor=orange]
\psSolid[args=my_cube 6,linecolor=yellow]
\psSolid[args=my_cube 7,linecolor=magenta]
\end{pspicture}
\newpage}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this nice animation, but I want to include it into a report - animation is probably not the best way to implement this. But I will keep in mind for later presentations!

Comment: The animation has no sense here! It should only show the that every viewpoint is possible.