# Draw realistic 3D crystal structures (diamond)

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, pstricks, 3d, asymptote

I want to draw a realistic 3D crystal structure, e.g. diamond. The point where I struggle is to draw connecting 3D rods.

### Desired result

In the end it should describe the cubic cell of diamond, e.g. like the following picture from [Phase Transformations & Complex
Properties Research Group](http://www.msm.cam.ac.uk/phase-trans/2003/MP1.crystals/MP1.crystals.html). [image: Cubic cell of diamond]

### Comments

- To me it seemed not reasonable at all to use `TikZ` as the picture gets useless at different view angles as I recognized by asking the question [Unordered layers in tikz-3dplot (3d effect)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/138824/25077).
- Even the example in question [Help creating solid cylinders along a path in Tikz for crystal lattice diagram](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/114815/25077) using `asymptote` has unrealistic 3D layers (i.e. all atoms in front of the connecting rods - and the atoms are semitransparent in contrast to the image presented there).

### Example

Here is a `pstricks` example:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{pst-solides3d}

\begin{document}
 \begin{pspicture}(-4,-4)(14,14)
  \psSolid[object=cylindre, h=6, r=1, fillcolor=yellow](0,0,0)
  \psSolid[object=sphere, r=2, fillcolor=red!25](0,0,0)
  \psSolid[object=sphere, r=2, fillcolor=red!25](0,0,6)
 \end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: that is not really easy. See http://melusine.eu.org/syracuse/pstricks/pst-solides3d/doc/doc-exemples-solides3d/?page=10 and following pages

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Since you included the `asymptote` tag, I assume you will not object to an Asymptote solution:

```
%process:
% pdflatex filename.tex
% asy filename-*.asy
% pdflatex filename.tex
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{asymptote}
\begin{document}
\begin{asy}
import three;
settings.render=8;
settings.prc=false;
size(10cm);

currentprojection = orthographic((3,4,5));

material spherecolor = material(diffusepen=black, ambientpen=gray(0.1), specularpen=white);
material cylcolor = material(diffusepen=white, ambientpen=white);

real cylRadius = 0.1;
real sphereRadius = 0.2;

void drawRod(triple a, triple b) {
  surface rod = extrude(scale(cylRadius)*unitcircle, axis=length(b-a)*Z);
  triple orthovector = cross(Z, b-a);
  if (length(orthovector) > .01) {
    real angle = aCos(dot(Z, b-a) / length(b-a));
    rod = rotate(angle, orthovector) * rod;
  }
  draw(shift(a)*rod, surfacepen=cylcolor);
}

void drawSphere(triple center) {
     draw(shift(center)*scale3(sphereRadius)*unitsphere, surfacepen=spherecolor);
}

triple a = O;
triple b = X;
triple c = 2Z;

drawSphere(a);
drawSphere(b);
drawSphere(c);
drawRod(a,b);
drawRod(b,c);
\end{asy}
\end{document}
```

gives the output

[image]

Comment: Could you provide a bigger one?

Comment: @Marienplatz: If this is a joke that the image I've uploaded is a bit large, I agree but am not sure how to change that. Otherwise, I don't understand your request; are you asking for a picture with more nodes?

Comment: The former is correct. :-)

Comment: @CharlesStaats Very nice solution. It's a pitty that `render=0` never really works on such pictures, though (`render=8` is fine of course, but I simply like vector images :)). I've taken the liberty of scaling down your output picture: I usually use something like `<img src="http://i.stack.imgur.com/Umw1B.png" height="400">` for that. I hope you don't mind.

Comment: @Philipp: Great improvement. I'll remember that for the future.

Comment: @CharlesStaats Glad I could help. Usually your the one helping me :)

Answer (score 21):

According to the hints in the answer of Charles Staats, I wrote the explicit code in `asymptote` ([page of the developper](http://www.piprime.fr/asymptote/)).

### Resulting figure - unit cell of diamond

[image]

### Latex file with asymptote code

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{asymptote}

\begin{document}
\begin{asy}
import three;
settings.render=8;
settings.prc=false;
size(10cm);

//currentprojection=perspective((45,45,30));
currentprojection = orthographic((3,6,1));

material sphereCcolor = material(diffusepen=black, ambientpen=gray(0.1), specularpen=white);
material cylcolor = material(diffusepen=white, ambientpen=white);

real cylRadius = 0.1;
real sphereRadius = 0.25;

void drawRod(triple a, triple b) {
  surface rod = extrude(scale(cylRadius)*unitcircle, axis=length(b-a)*Z);
  triple orthovector = cross(Z, b-a);
  if (length(orthovector) > .01) {
    real angle = aCos(dot(Z, b-a) / length(b-a));
    rod = rotate(angle, orthovector) * rod;
  }
  draw(shift(a)*rod, surfacepen=cylcolor);
}

void drawCarbon(triple center) {
     draw(shift(center)*scale3(sphereRadius)*unitsphere, surfacepen=sphereCcolor);
}

triple Aa = (0,0,0);
triple Ab = 4X;
triple Ac = 4Y;
triple Ad = 4X+4Y;
triple Ae = 2X+2Y;
triple Ba = 1X+1Y+1Z;
triple Bb = 3X+3Y+1Z;
triple Ca = 2X+2Z;
triple Cb = 2Y+2Z;
triple Cc = 4X+2Y+2Z;
triple Cd = 2X+4Y+2Z;
triple Da = 3X+1Y+3Z;
triple Db = 1X+3Y+3Z;
triple Ea = 4Z;
triple Eb = 4X+4Z;
triple Ec = 4Y+4Z;
triple Ed = 4X+4Y+4Z;
triple Ee = 2X+2Y+4Z;

drawRod(Ba,Aa);
drawRod(Ba,Ae);
drawRod(Bb,Ae);
drawRod(Bb,Ad);
drawRod(Ba,Ca);
drawRod(Ba,Cb);
drawRod(Bb,Cc);
drawRod(Bb,Cd);
drawRod(Da,Ca);
drawRod(Da,Cc);
drawRod(Db,Cb);
drawRod(Db,Cd);
drawRod(Da,Eb);
drawRod(Da,Ee);
drawRod(Db,Ee);
drawRod(Db,Ec);

drawCarbon(Aa);
drawCarbon(Ab);
drawCarbon(Ac);
drawCarbon(Ad);
drawCarbon(Ae);
drawCarbon(Ba);
drawCarbon(Bb);
drawCarbon(Ca);
drawCarbon(Cb);
drawCarbon(Cc);
drawCarbon(Cd);
drawCarbon(Da);
drawCarbon(Db);
drawCarbon(Ea);
drawCarbon(Eb);
drawCarbon(Ec);
drawCarbon(Ed);
drawCarbon(Ee);

// Frame
material framecolor = material(diffusepen=white, ambientpen=yellow);
void drawFrame(triple a, triple b) {
  surface rod = extrude(scale(.5*cylRadius)*unitcircle, axis=length(b-a)*Z);
  triple orthovector = cross(Z, b-a);
  if (length(orthovector) > .01) {
    real angle = aCos(dot(Z, b-a) / length(b-a));
    rod = rotate(angle, orthovector) * rod;
  }
  draw(shift(a)*rod, surfacepen=framecolor);
  draw(shift(b)*scale3(cylRadius)*unitsphere, surfacepen=framecolor);
}
drawFrame((0,0,0),4X);
drawFrame((0,0,0),4Y);
drawFrame((0,0,0),4Z);
drawFrame(4X,4X+4Y);
drawFrame(4X,4X+4Z);
drawFrame(4Y,4Y+4X);
drawFrame(4Y,4Y+4Z);
drawFrame(4Z,4X+4Z);
drawFrame(4Z,4Y+4Z);
drawFrame(4X+4Y+4Z,4Y+4Z);
drawFrame(4X+4Z,4X+4Y+4Z);
drawFrame(4X+4Y,4X+4Y+4Z);
\end{asy}
\end{document}
```

Comment: very nice, I inserted a higher resolution image, you can roll back the change if you feel it's overkill, but I felt a prettier picture would do more justice to your code.

Comment: this is my first time using asypmtote. For some reason, when I use your code, I get no matching function 'material(pen diffusepen, pen ambientpen)' 

Other asymptote codes work just fine

Answer (score 8):

You want hidden lines and surfaces, the reason why you have to collect all objects by a significant name and then build a fusion object:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{pst-solides3d}

\psset{lightsrc=viewpoint,viewpoint=80 10 10 rtp2xyz,Decran=40}
\begin{document}
 \begin{pspicture}[solidmemory](-4,-4)(14,14)
  \psset{object=sphere,r=2,fillcolor=red!25,action=none}
  \psSolid[object=cylindre,h=6,r=0.5,fillcolor=yellow,name=C](0,0,0)
  \psSolid[name=S1](0,0,0)
  \psSolid[name=S2](0,0,6)
  \psSolid[name=S3](0,6,6)
  \defFunction[algebraic]{FIV}(t){0}{t}{t}% x(t)=0, y(t)=t, z(t)=t
  \psSolid[object=courbe,range=0 6,ngrid=16 16,function=FIV,r=0.5,
           fillcolor=black!20,name=L1]
%
  \psSolid[object=fusion,base=C S1 S2 S3 L1,linewidth=0.2pt,action=draw**]  
 \end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]