# Draw cylinder from pst-solides3d "lying down"

Tags: pst-solides3d

I would like to draw a 'horizontal' cylinder connecting the two upper spheres from Herbert's answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/141453/15874).

I have looked at the [`pst-solides3d` manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pstricks/contrib/pst-solides3d/pst-solides3d-doc.pdf) but I cannot find out how to do that.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

no need for defining a parametric function. Simply rotate the cylinder:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-solides3d}

\psset{lightsrc=viewpoint,viewpoint=80 10 10 rtp2xyz,Decran=40}
\begin{document}
 \begin{pspicture}[solidmemory](-4,-4)(14,14)
  \psset{object=sphere,r=2,fillcolor=red!25,action=none}
  \psSolid[object=cylindre,h=6,r=0.5,fillcolor=yellow,name=C](0,0,0)
  \psSolid[name=S1](0,0,0)
  \psSolid[name=S2](0,0,6)
  \psSolid[name=S3](0,6,6)
  \psSolid[object=cylindre,h=8,r=0.5,RotX=-45,
           fillcolor=black!20,name=L1]
  \psSolid[object=cylindre,h=6,r=0.5,RotY=90,RotZ=90,
           fillcolor=green!20,name=L2](0,0,6)
  \psSolid[object=fusion,base=S1 S2 S3 C L1 L2,linewidth=0.2pt,action=draw**]  
 \end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice. Just out of curiosity: Why did you define a function for the slanted cylinder in your original answer?

Comment: just for fun ...

Comment: @texenthusiast: You'll find _a lot_  of examples in your local TeX distribution: `$TEXMF/doc/latex/pstricks-examples/`

Comment: @texenthusiast: `texdoc` refers only to the main documentation. And the quick ref is an additional documentation, like the other ones. What do you mean by "english contents"?

Comment: http://comedy.dante.de/~herbert/Books/ For texdoc write to http://tug.org/mailman/listinfo/texdoc

Answer (score 4):

The default cylinder shape is vertical. Like the slanted one, you have to specify the horizontal one using a parametric function. Here they are (without the balls):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-solides3d}% http://ctan.org/pkg/pst-solides3d

\psset{lightsrc=viewpoint,viewpoint=80 10 10 rtp2xyz,Decran=40}
\begin{document}
 \begin{pspicture}[solidmemory](-4,-4)(14,14)
  \psset{object=sphere,r=2,fillcolor=red!25,action=none}
  \psSolid[object=cylindre,h=6,r=0.5,fillcolor=yellow,name=C](0,0,0)
  %\psSolid[name=S1](0,0,0)
  %\psSolid[name=S2](0,0,6)
  %\psSolid[name=S3](0,6,6)
  \defFunction[algebraic]{FIVa}(t){0}{t}{t}% x(t)=0, y(t)=t, z(t)=t
  \psSolid[object=courbe,range=0 6,ngrid=16 16,function=FIVa,r=0.5,
           fillcolor=black!20,name=L1]
  \defFunction[algebraic]{FIVb}(t){0}{t}{6}% x(t)=0, y(t)=t, z(t)=6
  \psSolid[object=courbe,range=0 6,ngrid=16 16,function=FIVb,r=0.5,
           fillcolor=green!50,name=L2]
%
  \psSolid[object=fusion,base=C L1 L2,linewidth=0.2pt,action=draw**]  
 \end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

`FIVa` is associated with the diagonal cylinder, and `FIVb` is associated with the horizontal cylinder. The parametric function `FIVb(t)=(x(t),y(t),z(t))` has a fixed `x` and `z` coordinate. Only the `y` coordinate changes, making it lay horizontally.

---

Here's a take on the entire structure at a higher resolution (or `ngrid`), balls included:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-solides3d}% http://ctan.org/pkg/pst-solides3d

\psset{lightsrc=viewpoint,viewpoint=80 10 10 rtp2xyz,Decran=40}
\begin{document}
 \begin{pspicture}[solidmemory](-4,-4)(14,14)
  \psset{object=sphere,r=2,fillcolor=red!25,action=none,ngrid=40 40}
  \psSolid[object=cylindre,h=6,r=0.5,fillcolor=yellow,name=C](0,0,0)
  \psSolid[name=S1](0,0,0)
  \psSolid[name=S2](0,0,6)
  \psSolid[name=S3](0,6,6)
  \defFunction[algebraic]{FIVa}(t){0}{t}{t}% x(t)=0, y(t)=t, z(t)=t
  \psSolid[object=courbe,range=0 6,ngrid=40 40,function=FIVa,r=0.5,
           fillcolor=black!20,name=L1]
  \defFunction[algebraic]{FIVb}(t){0}{t}{6}% x(t)=0, y(t)=t, z(t)=6
  \psSolid[object=courbe,range=0 6,ngrid=40 40,function=FIVb,r=0.5,
           fillcolor=green!50,name=L2]
%
  \psSolid[object=fusion,base=C L1 L2 S1 S2 S3,linewidth=1sp,action=draw**]  
 \end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I hope you are not offended by me changing the accepted answer to Herbert's. You did exactly what I asked for but Herbert improved on his previous code.

Comment: @SvendTveskæg: No problem.